# Visualización de errores PHP

Tags: php, docker

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con mi entorno local.
Tengo una api levantada en docker y no me está ruteando bien los errores, simplemente me devuelve:

```
{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

Si pusheo esto al entorno dev me marca específicamente el motivo y la línea de error.

Fui a **php.ini**, habilité la visualización de errores de la siguiente forma:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
```

El problema es que cuando reinicio el contenedor de la api se reestablece el archivo y queda todo deshabilitado.

Alguien sabe qué puedo hacer para que esto no suceda?

Comment: y no sera que hace falta algo como: ini_set('html_errors', true);

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres persistir la configuración?

Comment: Claro, quiero que se mantengan las configuraciones que defino en php.ini luego de reiniciar el contenedor. Encontré algún tutorial que propone hacer un backup de la imagen, modificarla y montar esa en lugar de la que estoy creando con docker-compose. Esta opción no me resulta práctica porque ejecuta el contenedor fuera del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Si querés persistir el php.ini (o cualquier otro archivo), más allá del ciclo de vida del contenedor tenés dos opciones:

1. Copiarlo durante la creación de la imagen (Agregar un comando COPY o ADD al Dockerfile)
2. Montar un volumen que lo contenga.

Para desarrollo lo más conveniente es usar la segunda, de esa forma cualquier cambio que hagas en tu host se verá reflejado inmediatamente en el contenedor.

Para producción es más conveniente el primero para estar seguro de lo que hay en el entorno de ejecución.